# How to send the right file with discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I am building a bot that sends a txt file based on a command.
Problem is that when two people send the same command at the same time, the bot only sends one of the two twice, which is something I should avoid at all costs.

Do you have any solutions?
I tried to come up with a solution but it didn't work: I tried to delete the file right after it has been sent, but as I said, it didn't work.

NOTE: the bot successfully sends two embeds with the correct information, but then sends two identical files (always the one generated by the second request)

Here's the code of the command:

```
@bot.command(name='sendfile', help='Sends a file', pass_context=True)
async def quick(ctx, *args):
    try:
        arg1 = str(args[0]) 
        arg2 = args[1].capitalize()
        arg3  = args[2].upper()
        quantity = args[3]
        generate_file(order_id, arg2, quantity)
    
    except:
        embed = Embed(title="FILE GENERATION", description="An error has occurred. Please retry", color=16711702)
        fields = [("Error ID", "1", False)]
        for name, value, inline in fields:
            embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)
        
        print(f"{bcolors.FAIL} [{datetime.now()}] - ERROR {bcolors.ENDC}")
        raise TypeError
        
    
    
    embed = Embed(title="FILE GENERATION", description="FILE DETAILS", color=15859711)
    fields = [("ARG 1", f"{arg1}", False), ("Arg2", f"{arg2}", False), ("arg3", f'{arg3}',False), ("Quantity", f"{quantity}", False)]
    
    for name, value, inline in fields:
        embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    print(f"{bcolors.OKCYAN} [{datetime.now()}] - Command successfully executed! {bcolors.ENDC}")
    with open("generated_file.txt", "rb") as file:
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(file, "generated_file.txt"))
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: can you also add the `generate_file` function? Maybe instead of saving the file you could simply return a `discord.File` instance

Comment: solved, but thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with it solves the problem but it's not the best, but it works.

The idea is basically that I generate an alphanumeric string and include that in the file name.
e.g.: 'file_fu56d.txt'

After creation, I send it over to discord and then delete it.

Here's some code:

```
list= []
random_string = get_random_string(5)
for p in range(0, int(quantity)):
   to_append = f'{arg1}-something-{arg2}-soimething_else-{arg2}\n'
   list.append(to_append)
    
    # writes the txt file assigning each element of the list to each line
with open(f'file_{random_string}.txt', 'w') as file: 
    file.writelines(list)
print(f'[{datetime.now()}] - {quantity} lines successfully generated.')

    # opens the file and sends it to discord
with open(f"file_{random_string}.txt", "rb") as file:
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(file, f"file_{random_string}.txt"))
    print(f"[{datetime.now()}] - File successfully sent! ")

    # deletes the file
os.remove(f'file_{random_string}.txt')
print(f"[{datetime.now()}] - 'file_{random_string}.txt' successfully deleted!")
```